# Need jQuery Content Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am unable to get the correct title for this, please change the title if you get appropriate one :)

This is what i am having

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer">
     <div>
         Div content Here  [ always either embed or object or image ]
     </div>
     xtra noise
  </div>

  <div class="innerContainer">
     <div>
         Div content Here
     </div>
     xtra noise
  </div>

  <div class="innerContainer">
     <div>
         Div content Here
     </div>
     xtra noise
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, what i need is this
http://sketchfu.com/drawing/876520-what-do-i-need-
**Note** *sketchfu is pathetic for drawing.*

Is there any jQuery plugin which can do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get the title of the current slide and is 'xtra noise' the title value?

Comment: Rakesh: Oops misread lol, try easySlider, its a personal favorite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of content sliders: http://visionwidget.com/inspiration/web/295-jquery-content-sliders.html

I have used and like: http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

Comment: i like jFlow and EasySlider 1.7. Thnx